# what is the difference between employee and staff and worker

Tags: differences

I am reading Human Resource(HR) book, and I can not understand `employee`, `staff` and `worker`. 
Please explain in detail, thank!

Comment: There is no meaningful "difference" in your context. From the HR perspective, *employees, staff,* and *workers* all simply mean the people paid wages by the company, towards whom the company has certain legal and moral obligations. The terms may have slightly different connotations in various contexts, but nothing that can usefully be summarised here to explain why the person who wrote your HR book might have chosen one over another at any given point in the text.

Comment: Or... if your HR department **does** intend there to be a meaningful difference, then the terms will be explained somewhere locally (in the handbook, or on the company intranet, for example). Without any context -- at least one quote and more helpfully more than one containing each word -- there isn't enough information here to provide any sort of answer. Even with that, FumbleFingers may well be right and each word means the same thing. They simply used different words to produce a bit of variety in the handbook.

Comment: I would say that staff is usually used to denote those that support the director but that are placed above the people doing the manual labour on the work floor (workers). Both workers and staff are employees (those that do something for a firm and get paid for it).

Comment: Often the distinction will be determined by the way they are paid. In Britain manual workers tend to be hourly rated and are paid for overtime, often at premium rates. Staff tend to be paid monthly based on an annual salary and, (senior ones at any rate) are not paid for overtime. In some companies, however, they may be eligible for attractive performance bonuses. The term 'employee' is partly a legal one and covers anyone who works for a business other than its owners/directors.

Comment: the difference between worker and employee - the employee washes his hands after peeing  and the worker before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often the distinction will be determined by the way they are paid. In Britain manual workers tend to be hourly rated and are paid for overtime, often at premium rates. Staff tend to be paid monthly based on an annual salary and, (senior ones at any rate) are not paid for overtime. In some companies, however, they may be eligible for attractive performance bonuses. The term 'employee' is partly a legal one and covers anyone who works for a business other than its owners/directors. –  WS2 6 hours ago